# Riemann hypothesis and ternary Goldbach

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, goldbach-type-problems

Is there any result of the following shape: There exists an absolute constant $\delta>0$ such that the Riemann hypothesis for some $L$-functions is equivalent to the following estimate for all fixed $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ odd, $$ \sum_{\substack{ n_1,n_2,n_3 \in (\mathbb N\cap [1,n] )^3\\n_1+n_2+n_3=n}}
\Lambda(n_1)\Lambda(n_2)\Lambda(n_3) =\frac{n^2}{2} \mathfrak{S}(n) +O_\epsilon(n^{2-\delta+\epsilon})?$$
Here $\mathfrak{S}(n)=\prod_p \sigma_p(n) $, where
$$\sigma_p(n):= p (p-1)^{-3}\#\{n_1,n_2,n_3 \in (\mathbb F_p^*)^3: n_1+n_2+n_3=n\} .$$

Simpler question: assuming GRH for all Dirichlet $L$-functions what is the best known error term?

Comment: What is $N$? Do you mean $n$?

Comment: The sum factors, there must be some typos

Comment: Both things were typos, they are now fixed.